# CSS transition not working properly in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out why my CSS transitions aren't working properly. So I have a class called `visible` that I'm using to attempt to fade in and fade an element by toggling. The CSS is

```
ul.feature-points { list-style: none; width: 36%; position: absolute; top: 19%; left: 2.4em; padding-left: 0; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease; transition: opacity 2s ease; }
ul.feature-points.visible { opacity: 1;  }
```

and the lines of jQuery that attempt to invoke the transition are

```
retobj.$layer.show();

retobj.$layer.find('.feature-points').addClass('visible');
```

For some reason, the transition doesn't work when that happens and I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the fact that immediately before I'm making one of it's ancestors show. Maybe the events are conflicting in the browser or something? But I tried in multiple browsers and it does the same thing.

What's strange is that if I think type in

```
$('.feature-points').toggleClass('visible');
```

repeatedly to the console then I can see these elements transitioning properly.

Any ideas  as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: `retobj.$layer.find('.feature-points').length`  check if this returns any non-zero value. I guess it might be 0 that's why

Comment: i have a fiddle and it working good, using `hover` and `toggleClass`

Comment: You need the transition on both classes - on the standard class, my guess is it works... but on the visible class there is no transition -- so, you'd only see the transition upon removing `.visible` at times. If you want the transition both ways, both classes need the transition property.